# How to enable Hardware acceleration

Tags: nvidia, graphics, video

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and I have an NVIDIA GTX 1070 OC. I added this PPA:

`ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

And I installed the nvidia-370 package for my GTX 1070 OC. Then I played a 4K video file with HEVC Codec and excepted for hardware acceleration to be enabled to hardware decoding HEVC codec, but mpv player was using the software decoding mod. How can i fix this issue?

Comment: While that gpu should support hevc decoding maybe install vdpauinfo & ck. for support with `vdpauinfo` (- will list supported ) If good run mpv with `--hwdec=vdpau --vo=vdpau` options, see if it uses hw decoding.

Comment: output vdpauinfo 
https://paste.ubuntu.ir/hnfl

Comment: and this output mpv when play 4k  HEVC codec https://paste.ubuntu.ir/ixqa mpv use software decoding mod

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer: Sorry but it's an answer for VLC, not mpv player. I believe there are bugs or lack of support in mpv player because in my setup, while VLC is working fine with low CPU, mpv player doesn't. You may face the FFmpeg multithreading issue (see point 4).*

I've really struggled to get this working, and I'm a bit disapointed of the limited NVIDIA GTX 10*0 (Pascal) HEVC support compared to AMD.

### 0. Check HEVC profile support

Edit: NVIDIA VDPAU driver now supports HEVC Main 10 profile on Linux since version 450.51+

**Check media file HEVC profile:** You can check your file HEVC profile by right-clicking on your file >  `Properties` > `Audio/Video` tab > `Video` > `Codec`.

**Check driver HEVC profiles support:** Switch to the NVIDIA proprietary drivers (see below) and run:

```
$ vdpauinfo
Information string: NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  367.57  [crop]
Decoder capabilities:

name                        level macbs width height
----------------------------------------------------
[crop]
HEVC_MAIN                      153 262144  8192  8192
HEVC_MAIN_10                   --- not supported ---
HEVC_MAIN_STILL                --- not supported ---
HEVC_MAIN_12                   --- not supported ---
HEVC_MAIN_444                  --- not supported ---

$ vdpauinfo
Information string: NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  450.80.02  [crop]
Decoder capabilities:

name                        level macbs width height
----------------------------------------------------
[crop]
HEVC_MAIN                      153 262144  8192  8192
HEVC_MAIN_10                   153 262144  8192  8192
HEVC_MAIN_STILL                --- not supported ---
HEVC_MAIN_12                   153 262144  8192  8192
HEVC_MAIN_444                  --- not supported ---
```

### 1. Switch to NVIDIA proprietary drivers

You need at least version R367 (`nvidia-367`).

```
 software-properties-gtk &
```

Go to `Additional drivers` tab, check `NVIDIA binary driver` and `Apply` the changes.

### 2. Enable hardware acceleration in VLC

Of course, you must enable hardware acceleration in VLC > `Tools` > `Preferences` (`Simple`) > `Input / Codecs` > `Hardware-acceleration decoding` = `Auto`. For NVIDIA, you can choose `VDPAU video decoder` explicitely.

### 3. Update VLC to 2.2.4 or 3.0

There are several bugs in VLC 2.2.2 (Ubuntu 16.04), fixed in later versions (*see: [changelog](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc-branch/NEWS)*), that lead to this misleading error:

```
$ vlc --version
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax
$ vlc <file>
[crop]
[00007fa4b42cc5d8] vdpau_avcodec generic error: unsupported codec 1211250229 or profile 1
```

That's clearly a misleading and buggy error. Hard to tell, but `1211250229` does mean `AV_CODEC_ID_HEVC` *(can be checked by compiling with `rustc` this [rusty code](http://pastebin.com/iRFrBpuL))*. And we've seen from `vdpauinfo` that HEVC profile `1` ([= `Main`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/libavcodec_2avcodec_8h.html#af7a5858840ff5f2c70ae33a2cd1f4228)) is supported.

At this time, VLC 2.2.4 is not available from the official VLC PPA (*[check stable version here](https://launchpad.net/%7Evideolan/+archive/ubuntu/stable-daily)*). So upgrade to VLC 3.0 from the master branch (*[check master version here](https://launchpad.net/%7Evideolan/+archive/ubuntu/master-daily)*) but keep in mind it's a nightly release:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install vlc
$ vlc --version
[crop]
VLC version 3.0.0-git Vetinari
```

### 4. Temporarily disable VLC FFmpeg multithreading

As this is not enough, you may now face this issue:

```
$ vlc <file> --verbose
[crop]
[00007f6bc4ccc688] avcodec decoder warning: thread type 1: disabling hardware acceleration
```

Explainations on [this thread](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=134770#p446154) at VLC forum:

> It means you're using FFmpeg, which no longer allows enabling hardware
> acceleration and threading at the same time. You need to use libav
> [but] this is decided while compiling VLC. You can't change it at
> run-time.

On the same thread, there's a workaround: In VLC > Tools > Preferences (All) > Input / Codecs > Video codecs > **FFmpeg, change the value of `Threads` from `0` (auto) to `1`**.

And you're done!

But that's a manual workaround: keep in mind that to watch videos not GPU-accelerated, you should reset the VLC FFmpeg `Threads` setting to use all your CPU cores... or compile VLC from source with libav.

Comment: VDPAU 1.4 added support for HEVC_MAIN_10